# Survey of varieties of non-standard analysis?

Tags: reference-request, nonstandard-analysis

Is there a reliable, reasonably up-to-date, survey article doing a "compare and contrast" on  varieties of non-standard analysis?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best starting point is the detailed account by Hamkins [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/226169/what-are-the-advantages-of-the-more-abstract-approaches-to-nonstandard-analysis/226393#226393) which will hopefully be published in a more formal venue eventually.

Two approaches that are not discussed there in detail are Hrbacek's *relative set theory*, as well as the $\alpha$-theory of Di Nasso and collaborators.

Also, the new edition of *Nonstandard analysis for the working mathematician* by Loeb and Wolff seems promising; see [here](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9789401773263).  However I haven't been able to get my hands on a copy yet.

Such an article is [online here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.00425), soon to appear in *Real Analysis Exchange*.